# How do you autofill a field in WP Contact 7 Form from a URL or redirect from the client side without web server access?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, redirect

I am attempting to autofill a form on a website that I don’t have access to change. Digging around the pages source info, I’ve figured out the form is a WordPress Contact 7 form. One of the text boxes is "c-referred-by". I would like to have someone click on a link from my HTML email signature, and have it autofill my first and last name in this “Referred By” field.
I have been trying to use a GET request through the URL. Syntax of the URL I tried is as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/apply?c-referred-by=First+Last
```

I can tell the word press site is receiving the data, as when I inspect it, I can see my First Last name listed in the source, but the page doesn’t display the text for the user to see in the box. I have found ways to do this if I have access to the Server-side WordPress page, but I don’t.

Because this is in an email signature, I need to avoid anything but HTML in the signature as most email clients will not display JScript or PHP, and if they do they will be suspicious, and either strip the code or it may get caught in a SPAM filter.

I feel I will need to have an intermediary page between the email signature and the webform that can fill the information into, say a cookie, or some other recallable data system, then that page redirects to the page with the form, and populates it.

Flow of data image

[image]

I’m just not sure how to go about this?
Is there a better way I am not familiar with?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: There is a tutorial here on how to do it https://www.featheredowl.com/auto-populate-contact-form-7-input-fields-with-url-parameter/

Comment: Thank you for the link, but this would require me to have access to the Wordpress site form to add the plugin. I don't have that access sadly. I need to do this without adjusting the Wordpress code at all.